# styling not applying to paper-item

Tags: polymer

Has anyone else had any trouble using the provided paper-item element?  I've tried to use it several times, but no styling is being applied.

Haven't had any trouble with any other polymer element, just this guy.  Tried using the example exactly as listed in the documentation, but no luck:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">

<div class="holder" role="listbox">
  <paper-item>
    <paper-item-body two-line>
      <div>Profile Photo</div>
      <div secondary>Change your Google+ profile photo</div>
    </paper-item-body>
  </paper-item>
  <paper-icon-item>
    <iron-icon icon="communication:phone" item-icon>
    </iron-icon>
    <paper-item-body two-line>
      <div>(650) 555-1234</div>
      <div secondary>Mobile</div>
    </paper-item-body>
  </paper-icon-item>
  <paper-icon-item>
    <div class="avatar blue" item-icon></div>
    <paper-item-body two-line>
      <div>Alphonso Engelking</div>
      <div secondary>Change photo</div>
    </paper-item-body>
  </paper-icon-item>
</div>
```

Am I alone on this?  Unsure whether I'm some how using it wrong, or if there's a problem with the element.

---

Ah okay, the paper-item-body element needs to be imported separately from paper-item...  Once that is added, default styling is applied

Comment: The styling as per the documentation demo.  Such as the secondary text or making the icons appear.  The links are all being imported in the elements file but apparently not being used here.  https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-item?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=paper-item

Comment: are you including the `iron-icons` as well? `<link rel="import" href="../../iron-icons/iron-icons.html">`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I was able to sort it out just by importing the following components.

```
../bower_components/paper-item/paper-item-body.html"
../bower_components/paper-item/paper-icon-item.html"
../bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-item/paper-item-body.html">`

And then for styling use sample like below

```
paper-item.danger{
   background-color: crimson;
   border: solid thin transparent;
   border-radius: 3px;
}
paper-item-body{
   color: #fff;
   padding: 20px 0px;
   --paper-item-body-secondary:{
       color: #fff;
       padding:0px 20px;
       white-space: normal; //Otherwise text beyond paper-item will get hidden
    };
 }
```

With below code you will get output as in picture.

```
<paper-item class="danger">
   <paper-item-body two-line>
       <div>Main Heading</div>
       <div secondary>Detailed Message
       </div>
    </paper-item-body>
 </paper-item>
```

[image]